# Stop sidebar on end div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sidebar

Goodmorning,

Ive a information page with a sidebar on the right site of the page that follows the screen when scrolling but when he reach the and of the div its still following the page as.

```js
 var $sidebar = $("#sidebar"),
   $window = $(window),
   offset = $sidebar.offset(),
   topPadding = 230;

 $window.scroll(function() {
   if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
     $sidebar.stop().animate({
       marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
     });
   } else {
     $sidebar.stop().animate({
       marginTop: 15,
       marginBottom: 200
     });
   }
 });
```

```css
#sidebar {
  width: 190px;
}
#sidebar li {
  border-left: 1px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  border-top: 1px solid orange;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 8px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#sidebar li:hover {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #FF8D00;
  color: white;
}
#sidebar lu {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar li:hover a {
  color: white;
}
body {
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar" class="span3 over_inhoud rechts Padding-top-orange">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Agenda">Agenda</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#urenregistratie">Urenregistratie</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#rapportage">Rapportage</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Factureren">Factureren</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Koppelingen">Koppelingen</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#planning">Planning</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Boekhouden">Boekhouden</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Mobile">Mobile App</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Ontwikkeling">Ontwikkeling</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://www.clockwise.mar-bakker.nl/info.html

Comment: [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/MiguelR/Bybd5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use height of the div to get if you are reached at the bottom of the div or not and animate it in "else if".

You can get height of the div using

```
div_height = $("#InformatieDiv").height()
```

So there will be three branches as follows:

```
if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top){
  #CODE TO STOP SCROLLING UP
}else if($window.scrollTop() < (offset.top + div_height)){
  #CODE TO STOP SCROLLING DOWN
}else{
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have Twitter Bootstrap on your site, so why not to use Affix.js plugin from this framework: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix ??

Simply:

```
$('#sidebar ul').affix({...})
```

should do the job.

And in options You of course have possibility to set `bottom` param to stop affixing when container reaches specific position.